What are the implications of PLSQL_OPTIMIZE_LEVEL=2 and PLSQL_DEBUG=TRUE?
I have an Oracle database (19c EE) where several users develop PL/SQL Code. When I query the view USER_PLSQL_OBJECT_SETTINGS it shows me 700 entries with PLSQL_OPTIMIZE_LEVEL=2 and PLSQL_DEBUG=TRUE. I always thought, that there was no debug created when going higher than 1 with the optimize level ("Debugging data is not created above level 1" - Steven Feuerstein). Can you enable Debug for Level 2 manually and actually have the DB generate Debug Code? And will this still hurt performance?
